# How to select all posts from a table where content doesn't contain the stop words existing in a secondary table

Tags: mysql, stop-words

I have the table `posts` with fields `id`, `message_original` and table `spamfilters` with fields `id`, `spamterm` .

I want to select all records from table `posts` where the `message_original` doesn't contain the stopwords located in the table `spamfilters` in the column `spamterm` . Each spamterm is on a row.

How do I manage this in a MySQL query?

Comment: `SELECT posts.* FROM posts  WHERE posts.message_original  not in (SELECT spamfilters.spamterm FROM spamfilters)`

Comment: Use this, does this work ?

Comment: Well .. can't give the result I expect .. first of all .. you're looking for the message_original content in the spamterm .. but the content is like this:   message_original = "I did some test that I'm not proud of"  .. and you have the term 'test'   in the spamterm .. obviously I would expect more like having to split the message_original in words and then compare them somehow

Comment: So you have to use `not like *'spamfilters.spamterm'*`

Comment: To look for the ford in the sentence

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it like this and it simply works. How good a solution though I can't say .. but it works.

SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` JOIN `spamfilters` WHERE `posts`.`message_original` like CONCAT('%', `spamterm`,'%')